# How to send nested JSON input to RESTful web service in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

How can I send the following nested JSON input to REST web service and read the values in the service's class?

```
{
 "payload": {
   "objType": "",
      "props": {
        "propName1": "propValue1",
        "propName2": "propValue2"
      },
   "retProps": ["prop1", "prop2"]
   }
}
```

To read the JSON input which is **not** **nested**, I've created a class:

```
public class MessageInputJSON {

private String payload;
private String objType;
private String prop;
private String retProp;

    // Getters and Setters here
}
```

And to read the values, I have created the following class :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String readJSON(MessageInputJSON message) {

         String payload = message.getPayload();
         String objType = message.getObjType();

    }
```

But I do not know how to send the nested JSON input and read its value in Java

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the transfer Object with the same hierarchy of the json, with your sample the input dto must look like this :

```
public class Payload {
 private String objType;
 Props PropsObject;
 ArrayList < Object > retProps = new ArrayList < Object > ();
```

Full object : https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter/cb83de35

Comment: Thanks! and how to accept the values in the service class?

Comment: public String readJSON(@RequestBody MessageInputJSON message) {